# How to make a PLL output the phase modulo 360°?

Tags: digital-logic, control, pll

I have made a PLL to obtain the mechanical angle encoded in quadrature sine signals (the envelope of a resolver output) ; it implements: error=in-out is approximatively equal to sin(in-out)=sin(in)cos(out)-cos(in)sin(out)).

I tuned the controller with Simulink's control toolbox and the PLL works, however I can only seem to get unbounded angles out of it, i.e. the angle output increases with time without bounds beyond 360°. I tried putting a modulo 2*pi operation inside the PLL at this location, but it throws off everything and the loop fails (certainly because of non-linearity):

[image]

How to make this PLL output a bounded angle (between -180° and 180°)? Meaning, obtain a sawtooth between -180° and 180° on the considered block diagram.

Comment: In order to bind phase limits you are essentially measuring frequency and using edge detection to determine after each cycles if the time interval Is outside the frequency tolerance with some other criteria involved as well.  Essentially you are using a synchronous Type II phase/frequency detector like those optional in CMOS simple PLL’s. Infinite pull-in (Capture range) Freq error but poor phase noise immunity.

Comment: Excuse me, but you could have the resolver output amplitudes (with polarity) perfectly if you mixed them to 0Hz with the input of the resolver. Why in the hell you try to recreate the rotation? You have the axis position all the time available as DC voltages which present the sine and cosine  of the rotation angle You could use them where ever the axis position is needed as long as you use both of them. Convert it to -180 to +180 degrees only for displaying to humans which maybe cannot observe 2 phase signals.